# Error Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {0.1,0,1}. please help

Tags: probability-or-statistics, physics

I am making the code you can see below. I believe the error is that when I plug in values for x it also feeds back to the "dx" in the integration, how can I go around that?

```
    ClearAll["Global`*"];
s[x_, n_, \[Eta]_, k_] := n*\[Eta]^k*x^(2 k);

(*This is the Likliyhood L(Y|x)which is proportional to the number of \
experiments done*)
likeYX[x_, y_, n_, k_, \[Eta]_] := (
  Power[s[x, n, \[Eta], k], y]*Exp[-s[x, n, \[Eta], k]])/y!;

(*one can see here that the sum converges to 1*)
likeSum[x_, n_, k_, \[Eta]_] := 
 Sum[likeYX[x, y, n, k, \[Eta]], {y, 0, Infinity}]

evidance[y_, n_, k_, \[Eta]_] := 1/
  Integrate[likeYX[x, y, n, k, \[Eta]], {x, 0, 1}];

pxn[x_, y_, n_, k_, \[Eta]_] := 
  Simplify[likeYX[x, y, n, k, \[Eta]]*evidance[y, n, k, \[Eta]]];

numenatorSum[x_, n_, k_, \[Eta]_] := 
 Sum[pxn[x, y, n, k, \[Eta]]*likeYX[x, y, n, k, \[Eta]], {y, 0, 
   Infinity}]
ClearAll[n, k, \[Eta], x];
Table[{x, numenatorSum[x, 4, 2, 0.9]}, {x, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]
```

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2504040).

Comment: This is only a start, but I think your variable `x` in your `Integrate` in your `evidance` is conflicting with your assigning values to `x` in your `Table`. Try changing to `evidance[y_, n_, k_, \[Eta]_] := 1/  Integrate[likeYX[xx, y, n, k, \[Eta]], {xx, 0, 1}];` Next, if I change your decimal constants to exact rationals then MMA gives a `Sum` depending on the magnitude of the real part of `y`. That is probably a hint to study carefully.

Comment: it works but now it takes forever to compile as I put N[Table[{x, numenatorSum[x, 4, 2, 0.9]}, {x, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]]